# Mixed logit with only one choice situation/observation per individual - valid to use?

Tags: mixed-model, discrete-data, multinomial-logit, mlogit

I have data from an experiment where participants had to choose one of 12 alternatives. I analyzed the data with a conditional logit model. That is I used the attributes of the choices to explain choice behavior. I suspect heterogeneity in preferences and according to the mixed logit I fitted there is (that is there is significant variance in the random parameters). And the fit for the mixed logit is better than for the conditional logit.

Now what confuses me is this: I see that we can get individual parameters (nicely described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/c5.mxl.html)), but how consistent are these? And how valid is it to use such a model with only one observation per individual. One reason I ask is that one R package I used (apollo) printed this message when fitting the mixed logit:

> Inter-person draws are used without a panel structure. This is unusual.

Howerver, [another](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/c5.mxl.html) R package frames it more in the way of "if you have panel data, we can account for that":

> If there are repeated observations for the same individuals, the longitudinal dimension of the data can be taken into account in the mixed logit model, assuming that the random parameters of individual i are the same for all his choice situations.

I would like to know wheter it is just unusual to use a mixed logit with only one choice observation per individual or if it is unusual in the sense of one should not do that. Because as of now I would go with the mixed logit since the BIC favors the mixed logit, which is also confirmed by a likelihood-ratio test.

Here is a plot of the individual parameters for one predictor:
[image: plot of individual parameters for one predictor]

Almost all of the intervals overlap. In the [paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v079i02) of the R package I used a corresponding figure looks like this (in the model the figure is based on panel data was used with 12 choice observations per individual):
[image]

So I guess the more observations one has per individual the narrower the confidence intervals of the individual parameters get. **So my confusion boils down to this: in my case, is it valid to use a mixed logit? And if yes, what conclusions can I draw from the model? E.g., that there is heterogeneity in preferences but that we should not interpret the individual means because we only have one observation per individual?**

Comment: First of all this is not a good answer, I just wanted to follow the question since I can't use the comment option (I'm a new user). So sorry for that.
Actually I have the same question so I'd be happy if you tell me whether you got an answer or not. Another thing regarding my understanding, if you have one observation per individual, all independent variables for other alternatives not being faced by this individual should be zeros? Wouldn't this be considered overfitting? Still, this option is available and recommended by Train in his mixedlogit code for non-panel data. The notes are in his p